# TFS Release Management update config files

Tags: tfs, release-management

I am new to TFS's release management. I have beend using octopus deploy and I am super happy with how octopus deploy updates configuration files (web.config or app.config) without using tokens. Is there a similar way in TFS RM? Dont really want to have a config file for local development and one with tokens?

Any idea is welcome...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For handling configuration in  Release Management, there are two techniques  generally used **Config Per Environment** and **Tokenization**.

If you prefer a clean separation between build and deploy. To achieve that, recommend tokenizing configuration.

As you mentioned above, suggest you to use Config Per Environment.

> In “config per environment”, you essentially **hard-code a config
>   file per environment.** At deploy time, you overwrite the target
>   environment config with the config from source control. This could be
>   an **xcopy operation**, but hopefully something a bit more intelligent
>   – like an ARM Template param.json file. When you define an ARM
>   template, you define parameters that are passed to the template when
>   it is executed. You can also then define a param.json file that
>   supplies the parameters.

More details please take a look at this wonderful blog: [Config Per Environment vs Tokenization in Release Management](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/config-per-environment-vs-tokenization-in-release-management)